# I have a modal with two input fields title and postbody how can I insert the values to my database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my modal view form action is send to Post/addPost

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addPostModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header btn-primary">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="createPost" action="Post/addPost" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Enter title">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="postbody">Body</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="postBody" name="postBody" rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Post</button>
        </form>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my Post/addPost Controller

```
public function addPost()
{
        //$this->load->library('form_validation');
        $validator = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

        $validate_data = array(
            array(
                'field' => 'title',
                'label' => 'Title',
                'rules' => 'required'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'postBody',
                'label' => 'Body',
                'rules' => 'required'
            )
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($validate_data);
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">', '</p>');


        if($this->form_validation->run() === true) {

            $this->load->model('Post_model');

            if ($query = $this->Post_model->addPosts()) {

                $validator['success'] = true;
                $validator['messages'] = 'Successfully Posted';
            } else {
                $validator['success'] = false;
                $validator['messages'] = 'error';
            }

        } else {
            $validator['success'] = false;
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                $validator['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($validator);
}
```

This is my Post_model->addPosts

```
public function addPosts()
    {
        $new_post_insert_data = array(
            'post_title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'post_body' => $this->input->post('postBody')
            );

        $insert = $this->db->insert('posts', $new_post_insert_data);
        return $insert;

    }
```

This is my jquery ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#createPost").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
        var form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response) { 

                if(response.success == true) {
                    $("#messages").html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                      '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                      response.messages+
                    '</div>');
                    $('#registrationsuccess').html('Succesfully Registered Please Login').fadeIn('slow').delay(9000).fadeOut('slow');
                    $('#btnRegister').remove();

                    $("#signinForm")[0].reset();
                    $(".text-danger").remove();
                    $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');


                } else {
                    alert(response.success)
                    $.each(response.messages, function(index, value) {
                        var element = $("#"+index);

                        $(element)
                        .closest('.form-group')
                        .removeClass('has-error')
                        .removeClass('has-success')
                        .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                        .find('.text-danger').remove();

                        $(element).after(value);


                    });

                }
            } // /success
        });  // /ajax

        return false;
    }); 
});
```

I linked this script on my footer like this

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url("custom/js/post.js"); ?>"></script>
```

but when I click the submit post button on my modal and check the console why does it goes to a  different controller it goes to Users/register it was suppose to go to Post/addPost because that's what i put on my action form on my modal what could be wrong because i dont see any errors when i checked the console

Comment: instead of submit, can you please write the code on button click? also pass the parameters with name directly, instead of ```form.serialize()```.

Comment: what is your url for "Post/addPost", have you routing your action/controller with urls

Comment: @Gautam Rai on my jquery ajax script i use this url: form.attr('action'), and on my modal form action="Post/addPost"